# Convert shn to flac with one command in CLI?

Tags: command-line, flac, lossless

Everywhere I've googled they always convert shn to wav, and then to flac. It's really uncomfortable. How can I convert shn to flac withing one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gladly shntool finally implemented flac format support. So it's just:

```
shntool conv -o flac *.shn
```

Comment: Finally? shntool hasn't been updated since 2009, and has supported external encoders since 2003 at least.